# Pandas: Fill null values between dates

Tags: python-3.x, function, group-by, null

Consider following dataframe

| date | id | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 11 | 1 | 12 |
| 2022-01-02 | 11 | 2 | 13 |
| 2022-01-03 | 11 | NaN | NaN |
| 2022-01-04 | 11 | NaN | NaN |
| 2022-01-05 | 11 | 5 | 15 |
| 2022-01-01 | 22 | 11 | 3 |
| 2022-01-02 | 22 | NaN | NaN |
| 2022-01-03 | 22 | NaN | NaN |
| 2022-01-04 | 22 | NaN | NaN |
| 2022-01-05 | 22 | 12 | 34 |
| 2022-01-01 | 33 | 2 | 4 |
| 2022-01-02 | 33 | 4 | 8 |
| 2022-01-03 | 33 | NaN | NaN |
| 2022-01-04 | 33 | NaN | NaN |
| 2022-01-05 | 33 | NaN | NaN |
| 2022-01-01 | 44 | NaN | NaN |
| 2022-01-02 | 44 | 34 | 89 |
| 2022-01-03 | 44 | NaN | NaN |
| 2022-01-04 | 44 | 35 | NaN |
| 2022-01-05 | 44 | NaN | NaN |

The output which I am expecting should be:

1. grouped on id column
2. fill null only when the whole row is empty
3. fill null values on id grouped column only when an upper bound date is present. eg. for id 11, null imputation will happen for 2022-01-03 and 2022-01-04 only because 2022-01-05 is present. But for id 33 there will be no null value imputation as there are no values after 2022-01-03

Final Output:

| date | id | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 11 | 1 | 12 |
| 2022-01-02 | 11 | 2 | 13 |
| 2022-01-03 | 11 | 2 | 13 |
| 2022-01-04 | 11 | 2 | 13 |
| 2022-01-05 | 11 | 5 | 15 |
| 2022-01-01 | 22 | 11 | 3 |
| 2022-01-02 | 22 | 11 | 3 |
| 2022-01-03 | 22 | 11 | 3 |
| 2022-01-04 | 22 | 11 | 3 |
| 2022-01-05 | 22 | 12 | 34 |
| 2022-01-01 | 33 | 2 | 4 |
| 2022-01-02 | 33 | 4 | 8 |
| 2022-01-03 | 33 | NaN | NaN |
| 2022-01-04 | 33 | NaN | NaN |
| 2022-01-05 | 33 | NaN | NaN |
| 2022-01-01 | 44 | NaN | NaN |
| 2022-01-02 | 44 | 34 | 89 |
| 2022-01-03 | 44 | 34 | 89 |
| 2022-01-04 | 44 | 35 | NaN |
| 2022-01-05 | 44 | NaN | NaN |

I tried ffill() function but it does not take into consideration the issue mentioned in point 3

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule is backward fill but implement forward fill.

Sample data generate:

```
import pandas as pd

data_dict = {
    "date": ["2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-03", "2022-01-04", "2022-01-05",
             "2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-03", "2022-01-04", "2022-01-05",
             "2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-03", "2022-01-04", "2022-01-05",
             "2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-03", "2022-01-04", "2022-01-05"],
    "id": [11, 11, 11, 11, 11,
           22, 22, 22, 22, 22,
           33, 33, 33, 33, 33,
           44, 44, 44, 44, 44],
    "value1": [1, 2, None, None, 5,
               11, None, None, None, 12,
               2, 4, None, None, None,
               None, 34, None, 35, None],
    "value2": [12, 13, None, None, 15,
               3, None, None, None, 34,
               4, 8, None, None, None,
               None, 89, None, None, None]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
df
```

Create dummy fill indicator by using backward fill `bfill`:

```
df[['dum1', 'dum2']] = df.groupby('id')[['value1', 'value2']].bfill().notna()
```

Then using `groupby` foward fill `ffill`:

```
df[['fvalue1', 'fvalue2']] = df.groupby('id')[['dum1', 'dum2']].ffill()
```

Lastly combine:

```
df['nvalue1'] = np.where(df['dum1']==True, df['fvalue1'], np.NaN)
df['nvalue2'] = np.where(df['dum2']==True, df['fvalue2'], np.NaN)
```